# atmega128 helperror: expected ';' before numeric constant

Tags: atmega

Why is this happening?
I do not see any problems.
I can not sense what to fix.
help me!
../1105-1.c: In function 'E_Pulse':
../1105-1.c:23:2: error: expected ';' before numeric constant
../1105-1.c:25:2: error: expected ';' before numeric constant

These errors are per function.

```
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<util/delay.h>

#define TLCD_RS PORTB.0 
#define TLCD_RW PORTB.1 
#define TLCD_E PORTB.2 
#define TLCD_EN{TLCD_E = 0 ; TLCD_E = 1 ; }
#define DATA PORTC 

void Port_Init(void); 
void E_Pulse(void);
void Func_Set(void);
void TLCD_DATA(unsigned char);
void Init_LCD(void);
void Port_Init(void)
{
DDRB = 0xff;
DDRC = 0xff;
}
void E_Pulse(void)
{
TLCD_E = 1;
_delay_ms(5);
TLCD_E = 0;
}
void TLCD_DATA(unsigned char data)
{
DATA = data;
TLCD_EN;
}
void Init_LCD(void)
{
TLCD_E = 0;
_delay_ms(15);
Func_Set();
_delay_ms(10);
Func_Set();
_delay_ms(150);
Func_Set();
TLCD_DATA(0x0f);
E_Pulse();
TLCD_DATA(0x06);
E_Pulse();
TLCD_DATA(0x01);
E_Pulse();
}
void lcd_char(char s)
{
TLCD_RS = 1;
TLCD_DATA(s);
E_Pulse();
}
void main(void)
{
Port_Init();
Init_LCD();
    lcd_char('1');
    lcd_char('2');
    lcd_char('3');
    lcd_char('4');
while(1);
}
```

Comment: It seems that you are missing a semi-column symbol -   ;   
You have to check which is the line of the error and just insert it there

Comment: There is a semicolon in the error line.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the same error on lines 23 and 25 is a massive clue.

Commonly the error line number refers to the line after the one with the error, because that is where things become obviously wrong to the compiler.

Reproducing that function, and expanding out the macro gives the following code

```
void E_Pulse(void)
{
  PORTB.2 = 1;
  _delay_ms(5);
  PORTB.2 = 0;
}
```

PORTB.2 is invalid code, it looks a bit like accessing a struct but struct elements can't be numbers. So the compiler gets confused and throws errors, the semicolon was a bit misleading, generally it guesses better.

This isn't the way you control GPIO pins using the AVR system. I have linked to a reasonable looking tutorial below.

http://www.elecrom.com/avr-tutorial-2-avr-input-output/